# VSCode C/C++ IntelliSense identifier undefined, but can resolve definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

New install of VSCode. The only extension I have installed is the Microsoft C/C++ Intellisense plugin. Version 0.24.1

I'm working with a codebase that has some header files with `#define X foo` macros. In the `.cpp` files it underlines these in red and says "identifier X is undefined". However if I ctrl+click/F12 it takes me to the `.h` file(s) with the macro defined.

This is the only extension I have right now so I don't think it's an issue of plugins competing. It seems common to macros with multiple definitions. i.e. we have

`chipset1/include/registers.h` and

`chipset2/include/registers.h`

which might both `#define REG1 0xF00` or similar. However I only have `"${workspaceFolder}/chipset1/include"` in my `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file. So I don't know why it's searching the chipset2 definitions as well. Perhaps this is causing the issue and the error message is misleading and should really say something like "multiple definitions found"? Still unsure why this behavior is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after I switched the version of c++ to 20, but my `c_cpp_properties.json` was still set up for c++17.

I had set `tasks.json` as

```
"args": [
            ...,
            "-std=c++20"
        ],
```

The problem was fixed after I set (I was using the mingw compiler, not MS) in `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
"cppStandard": "gnu++20",
```

Comment: This was the problem for me, I had to go into C++ intellisense settings in VSCode and change the standard to c++20

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense works by running a compiler on the code, while the click-through resolutions seem to use the includePath specified in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`. You are likely missing `#include registers.h` in your source code file. Since `registers.h` is on your includePath, the click-through still works.

You can test this by compiling your code and seeing if it tells you you have undefined references.

As for your multiple references issue, I would double check which one is actually being included in your source code on the `#include` lines.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line in c_cpp_properties.json:
"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"

With:
"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools-tools"

Comment: Why? What does this do?