# VSCode: How to define unique includePaths for each core (sub-directories) in STM32h7 dual-core project within same git repo?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, stm32, include-path, stm32h7

I have a git repository for a STM32 H7 dual-core project. Opening the repo-level folder my structure looks like the following:

```
PARENT DIRECTORY (STM32H755)
├── .git
├── .vscode
│   └── c_cpp_properties.json
│
├── CM4
│   ├── Core
│   │   ├── Inc
│   │   │   └── .h files for CM4 only
│   │   └── Src
│   │       └── .c files for CM4 only
│   └── ...
│   
├── CM7
│   ├── Core
│   │   ├── Inc
│   │   │   └── .h files for CM7 only
│   │   └── Src
│   │       └── .c files for CM7 only
│   └── ...
│
├── Common
│   ├── Core
│   │   ├── Inc
│   │   │   └── .h files for BOTH CM4 and CM7
│   │   └── Src
│   │       └── .c files for BOTH CM4 and CM7
│   └── ...
│
```

I need to specify the includePath for each of the CM4 and CM7 cores independently, including that specific core's h files as well as the common h files.

How is this achieved?

The default path  within c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
 "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            ],
```

causes issues for similarly named files between the CM4 and CM7 (ie. main.h).

Conversely, using a core specific paths, such as the following for a CM4:

```
 "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/CM4/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Common/**"
            ],
```

causes issues for the other core's files (ie. CM7's main.h).

Comment: Why not eclipse-based IDE where you can have it out-of-the-box without any problems? I always wander why people want to make their lives harder

Comment: It's ok to wander, but ultimately looking to see if a solution in possible in VSCode so I can stay on my historically preferred path.

Comment: Sure, everyone can make its life as tough as one likes. Free world, free country, free citizens

Comment: Found a relevant discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57500703/7405580